# Keeping only certain columns of a data frame provided they match a condition

Tags: r

I am new to programming so do bear with me. I have a data frame with about 1500 rows and 1000 variables. I am trying to keep columns that only have binary values i.e. "0" or "1", NAs are also allowed, but discard all other columns that don't match this criteria. Is there a way of doing this without knowing in advance the column names which meet the criteria?

I have read up on the **dplyr** `filter()` function and also the base **R** subsetting  but none match what I am looking for.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269). This will make it much easier for others to help you.

Comment: I suspect you want this `df[colSums(df == 1|df == 0|is.na(df)) == nrow(df)]`

Comment: @Sotos! I will do my best next time to give a reproducible example. Thank you, the code worked out great as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
df <- data.frame(a=1:5,
                 b=c(0,1,0,1,0),
                 c=c(0,1,0,1,NA_real_),
                 d=c(0,1,0,1,2))

is_binary <- function(x){
  all(x %in% c(0,1,NA_real_))
}

df[,sapply(df, is_binary)]
```

Output:

```
  b  c
1 0  0
2 1  1
3 0  0
4 1  1
5 0 NA
```

Comment: Thank you! Did exactly what I was looking for

Answer (score 1):

The new features in `dplyr` 1.0.0 provide a simple solution to this: `select(.data, where(is.logical))`. Where `.data` is your tibble/data frame (provided your variables are of data type `logical`, i.e. `TRUE`/`FALSE`).

Comment: Thank you. I will try again when I have updated `dplyr`